# How to find operation names in tensorflow graph

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a model using Keras in Python, and I want to use that trained model in a Java program. I originally intended to use the Keras model directly in Java, but it seems that Keras 2.0 isn't well supported yet. So I converted my Keras model (stored in an .h5) into a tensorflow model (stored in a .pb). Now I want to use this model in my Java code. However, I need 3 strings to do so successfully:

1. "the tag identifying the specific metagraphdef to load"
2. The operation to feed data into the net
3. The operation to get the result of the net

I have little to no idea how to find these strings. I can't modify my model much at this point, especially because Tensorflow 2.0 removed `get_session()`, meaning I need to use Tensorflow 1.0, which keeps giving me errors when loading a model from Keras 2.0. I was able to list all of the operations for my model, but I don't know which one of the nearly 100 is correct. I also don't know the tag for the metagraphdef.

How would I find those 3 pieces of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed TensorFlow with pip (or something similar like conda, etc.) it should come with the `saved_model_cli` utility.

You can use it to get some insights from your exported model:

```sh
saved_model_cli show --dir <model_dir> --tag_set <tag> --signature_def <signature>
```

Find more informations in the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#details_of_the_savedmodel_command_line_interface).

This is the result from one of my model:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['float32_Input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 118)
      name: serving_default_float32_Input:0
  inputs['uint8_Input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_UINT8
      shape: (-1, 583)
      name: serving_default_uint8_Input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['tf_op_layer_ExpandDims'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: PartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

`float32_Input`, `uint8_Input`, `ExpandDims` were the names of my layers in Python. To use it in Java I had to use the names: `serving_default_float32_Input`, `serving_default_float32_Input` and `PartitionedCall`.